# How to get an application's GUID

Tags: windows, msi, application, guid

How can I get an application's GUID from an MSI file without installing it and searching for it in the registry? Is the GUID located in the MSI's properties? Or, can I retrieve it using Orca?

Comment: It's in the "Property" table, property name "ProductCode".  What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: Remove an application that isn't getting uninstalled automatically in group policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use orca, the Property table has the product code.

Comment: There's a ProductCode and UpdateCode, which are different IDs. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: [ProductCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370854(v=vs.85).aspx) uniquely identifies the "version" of the software. The [UpgradeCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372375(v=vs.85).aspx) is used by the Upgrade table to determine which versions can be upgraded.